# Slow DNS resolution inside docker container

Tags: docker, dns

I noticed that inside my docker containers the DNS resolution of hostnames is very slow, up to 5 seconds. On the docker host the resolution of the exact same hostname takes few milli seconds, inside a hosted container four to five seconds.

For example:

```
    dig www.googleapis.com

    ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u9-Debian <<>> www.googleapis.com
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50096
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 14, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1480
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;www.googleapis.com.        IN  A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    www.googleapis.com. 3422    IN  CNAME   googleapis.l.google.com.
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.16.202
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.21.202
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.21.234
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   216.58.214.74
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.16.170
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   216.58.208.42
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.22.42
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.22.74
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.22.106
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   216.58.206.10
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   172.217.23.170
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   216.58.205.234
    googleapis.l.google.com. 176    IN  A   216.58.210.10

   ;; Query time: 4003 msec
   ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
   ;; WHEN: Tue Jan 24 06:55:37 UTC 2017
   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 289
```

Please notice the query time of about 4 seconds.

The `resolv.conf` of my container looks like

```
    nameserver 127.0.0.11
    options ndots:0
```

where `127.0.0.11` seems to be the internal docker dns service.

I start docker-engine with `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"`, the host runs Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Is there any way to debug the slow DNS resolution or any known workaround?

Comment: 5 seconds? ```root@f97ab2baf3af:/var/www# time ping example.org
ping: example.org: Temporary failure in name resolution

real 0m20.027s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
```  here it used 20 seconds to realize it can't resolve `example.org` x.x

Comment: late to the party: in host /etc/resolv.com there are two hosts, but one is down
in host the failover is 1 sec, but in container the fallover is 4 seconds. .

Answer (score 2):

I have met the similar issue. Then I found the following issue.
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11407

I have noticed you already post this issue in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31960

---

## Lazy Temporary Workaround

In my scenario, these two workarounds are enough:

1. Add `--net "host"` as the argument in the `docker run` command
2. Add `--dns "127.0.0.11"`

The first is not secure, and it also mess up the mapping ports. But it works.

The second is using dns. 
`127.0.0.11` works in my desktop. But fails in other server. You could specify a DNS server welcomed in China, like in Shenzhen, `202.96.134.133` works fine.

That is because DNS `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` in container has aweful latency in mainland China.

---

You could do the experiment using

````
```bash
time docker run busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com

time docker run --net "host" busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com
time docker run --dns "127.0.0.11" busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com
time docker run --dns "202.96.134.133" busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com
```
````

Fun fact: in aliyun, `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` have been already accelerated.

---

## Yet another solution involves bridge configuration

https://gist.github.com/etuttle/bc1cd3814b984ec694d6#file-gistfile1-sh-L18-L43

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be create/update the file: `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with some DNS:

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1"]
}
```

And restart docker daemon:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```