# Network latency on docker container when it connects to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, dbatools

I have a python flask application running inside a docker container. And I am using `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` to test the network latency between my application and SQL Server (running on premise). I found that the network latency is very slow when it runs from a docker container but it is very fast when I run on a Mac host. The docker container is based on `ubuntu` and I installed `powershell` on it. `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` is running from powershell. I also installed `powershell` on my local Mac OS.

The result from my local is:

```
ExecutionCount     : 1
Total              : 220.91 ms
Average            : 220.91 ms
ExecuteOnlyTotal   : 154.21 ms
ExecuteOnlyAverage : 154.21 ms
NetworkOnlyTotal   : 66.69 ms
```

but the result from the docker container is:

```
ExecutionCount     : 1
Total              : 1.23 s
Average            : 1.23 s
ExecuteOnlyTotal   : 282.52 ms
ExecuteOnlyAverage : 282.52 ms
NetworkOnlyTotal   : 946.88 ms
```

You can see that there is a big network latency when it runs from docker. Is there anything wrong related to docker?

There is not much different if I ping the instance from container and local. But I do see performance different when a sql query is sent from container and local. That's why I need `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` to test network latency.

After some testing I found if I put the command `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` inside `pwsh -Command "Test-DbaNetworkLatency ... "` it will be very slow. But if I run `pwsh` to switch to powershell command then it runs as fast as my local. But how can I define a dockerfile to let the container initialize a `powershell` let me specify a `powershell` script as ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: It could be an issue with the linux powershell, which has [significant performance issues](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1954). To exclude powershell as a suspect, could you try a ping to the server from host and the container and see if there is any significant difference?

Comment: pint host doesn't make any different. But the query I sent to sql server gives me different performance that's why I want to use `Test-DbaNetworkLatency` to test network latency.

Comment: This link `significant performance issues` only tells initialization is slow. My command is running after power-shell initialised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow DNS resolution inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821857/slow-dns-resolution-inside-docker-container)