# Database calls are very slow from spring boot containerized service . Any Resolutions?

Tags: sql-server, docker, oracle11g, docker-swarm, docker-container

Spring boot Service is running in docker container
The database is on linux host outside docker environment .
The database calls are very slow after moving to docker container .
Can it be due to network latency or any suggestions ?
The execution time of the queries is same as earlier as per the oracle database reports
There is huge performance hit due to the database calls

Similar Q : [Network latency on docker container when it connects to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278991/network-latency-on-docker-container-when-it-connects-to-sql-server)